# NetworkOnMainThreadException inside AsyncTask inside onFacebookLogin

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask, sdk

I'm having this situations right here:

My LoginActivity, that extends from FacebookActionBarActivity run login method from an instance of my custom class named Session:

```
@Override
protected void onFacebookLogin(final GraphUser facebookUser, com.facebook.Response response) {

    User user = new User(this, facebookUser);
    Session preSession = new Session(this, user);

    preSession.setCallback(new Response() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Message m) {
            Log.i("LoginOk", "Yeaaaaaaaaah!: " + ((Session) m.getData()).toQueryString());
            hjClient.setSession((Session) m.getData());
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("hjClient", hjClient);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Message m) {
            //closeFacebookSession();
            if (m.getData() instanceof Exception) {
                ((Exception) m.getData()).getStackTrace();
            } else {
                Log.i("onError", m.getData().toString());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, m.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });

    preSession.login();
}
```

Session.login() is like this:

```
public void login() {

    RequestAsyncTask request = new RequestAsyncTask(getContext(), new Response() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Message m) {
            try {
                Log.i("onSuccess login", m.getData().toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(m.getData().toString());
                // Si no hay un atributo code o el atributo code es 0 entonces el mensaje
                // desde el servicio es un OK
                if (!jsonObject.has("code") || jsonObject.get("code").equals("0")) {
                    if (getCallback() != null) getCallback().onSuccess(new Message(new Session(jsonObject)));
                } else {
                    onError(new Message(jsonObject));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                onError(new Message(e));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Message m) {
            if (getCallback() != null) getCallback().onError(m);
        }
    });

    request.execute("method=sessionLogin&" + toQueryString());
}
```

It creates an instance of RequestAsyncTask. RequestAsyncTask extends from Java native AsyncTask and handle reponse messages. Here is RequestAsyncTask:

```
public class RequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

Context context;
String url;
List<NameValuePair> params;
Response callback;

// constructor

public RequestAsyncTask(Context context, Response callback) {
    super();
    setContext(context);
    setCallback(callback);
}

// methods

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getUrl());
        setParams(params[0].toString());
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(getParams()));
        return client.execute(post);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This Exception will be catched on onPostExecute and it will throw another Exception
        return e;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    if (getCallback() != null) {
        Log.i("postExecute", o.toString());
        if (!(o instanceof Exception)) {
            try {
                String httpResponse = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse((HttpResponse) o);
                //JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(httpResponse);
                //getCallback().onSuccess(new Message(jsonResponse));
                Log.i("httpResponse", httpResponse);
                getCallback().onSuccess(new Message(httpResponse));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("postExecuteRrror", e.toString());
                getCallback().onError(new Message(e));
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("Error en llamada", ":D");
            getCallback().onError(new Message((Exception) o));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm receiving a NetworkOnMainThreadException on PostExecute method of the RequestAsyncTask instance initiated in login method.

And here is the StackTrace:

```
04-26 14:08:52.571    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/FacebookActionBarActivity﹕ Logged in...
04-26 14:08:52.821    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 14:08:52.821    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 14:08:56.025    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/queryString:﹕ user_birthday=1991-01-03&user_email=agurodriguez@icloud.com&user_firstName=Federico&user_id=10206493058584965&user_lastName=Rodríguez&user_middleName=Agustín&user_sex=1
04-26 14:08:56.025    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/queryString:﹕ deviceId=3febed0b2be4bcb7&deviceManufacturer=samsung&deviceModel=GT-S7390L&deviceOS=Android Unknown 1&id=0&user_birthday=1991-01-03&user_email=agurodriguez@icloud.com&user_firstName=Federico&user_id=10206493058584965&user_lastName=Rodríguez&user_middleName=Agustín&user_sex=1
04-26 14:08:56.035    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/MeRequest﹕ GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"10206493058584965","first_name":"Federico","birthday":"01\/03\/1991","timezone":-3,"email":"agurodriguez@icloud.com","verified":true,"middle_name":"Agustín","name":"Federico Agustín Rodríguez","locale":"es_LA","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/10206493058584965\/","last_name":"Rodríguez","gender":"male","updated_time":"2014-06-12T02:59:52+0000"}}
04-26 14:08:57.346    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/postExecute﹕ org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@425125b0
04-26 14:08:57.346    9552-9552/net.agurodriguez.hoyjugamos I/postExecuteRrror﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

What I'm doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Is `RequestAsyncTask` your class? If so, please post it. Also, please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare Yes, RequestAsyncTask is mine. I just edited the post with your requirements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that is not a Java stack trace.

Second, move *all* your network I/O into `doInBackground()`. This includes your `handleResponse()` call.

Comment: First: Yes, I'm sorry. I should say Android native "AsyncTask"

Comment: Second: You're a genius! Moving my handleResponse() call to doInBackground method make the code works.